# Error refreshing materialized view fast with aggregates ORA-01792

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, materialized-views

while trying to refresh a materialized view fast with aggregates in Oracle 12c, I'm getting the error ORA-01792 "maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000". However, the view has less than 1000 columns; even adding up the columns of the base table (which is another fast materialized view), I'm not reaching the 1000. I have gone through all restrictions for materialized views with aggregates according to the Oracle manual and I'm almost sure I'm not violating any of them. Not sure if creating a fast MV over another fast MV has something to do.

The script comes as follows:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MVW_USER_PAYMENTS
TABLESPACE TESTING
NOCACHE
NOLOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOPARALLEL
BUILD IMMEDIATE
USING INDEX
            TABLESPACE TESTING_IDX
REFRESH FAST
START WITH TO_DATE('30-jul-2015 23:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
NEXT SYSDATE+1/24 
WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS 
SELECT 
           ID,
           YEAR,
           NAME,
           -- Summarised fields
           SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,  COUNT(TOTAL_AMOUNT) AS CNT_TOTAL_AMOUNT,
           SUM(VAL_INTEREST) AS VAL_INTEREST,  COUNT(VAL_INTEREST) AS CNT_VAL_INTEREST,
           .
           .
           .
       (more rows)
           .
           COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_RECORDS
FROM MVW_USER_PAYMENTS_ORIGINAL
GROUP BY 
           ID,
           YEAR,
           NAME;
```

Any hint is much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried with COMPLETE instead of FAST?

Comment: Yes, with a COMPLETE refresh works perfectly. But I need a FAST refresh because the table is way big (over 300 million records).